# "Error in plot_label (p=p . . . Unsupported class: prcomp"

Tags: r, pca, ggbiplot

I see the same problem reported recently (March 24, 2019).  Previously was able to use ggbiplot for prcomp object.  Now I get the error shown below:

Here is my code:

```
> pca<-prcomp(data,center=TRUE,scale=TRUE)

> library(ggbiplot)

> ggbiplot(pca)
```

get error:

```
Error in plot_label(p = p, data = plot.data, label = label,
label.label = label.label,  : Unsupported class: prcomp*
```

Comment: Can you add details about which version of `ggbiplot` you are using? I cannot confirm the issue with `ggbiplot_0.55`.

Comment: The problem was resolved after a fresh download of ggbiplot with updated components.  Thank you!